# Android 5.0 emulator not start

Tags: android, android-emulator

I downloaded the new android 5.0 sdk and sys-image, but if i would like to start an emulator with android 5.0 it not start just show me a black screen, whats the problem?

Comment: are you using the google api version?

Comment: no i use this:
Android 5.0 - API Level 21

Comment: if i select google api version, and i try to select intel x86 cpu i got this warning: This AVD may not work unless you install the Google APIs Intel Atom (x86) system image for Android 5.0 (API 21) first. but i have intel x86 sys image for android 5.0

Comment: greywolf82 thank you very much! now its working!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to turn on the option "Use host GPU".

Answer (score 3):

On my Mac I had already enabled Use Host GPU and that did not help me. I was using CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86_64) and then changed it to Intel Atom (x86) and then it launched.

Comment: +1 x64 fixed it for me. Along with the recommended answer "Use host GPU".

Answer (score 2):

Android SDK Platform-tools r21 or higher is required.

Android SDK Tools 23.0.5 or higher is required.

Answer (score 0):

I have Intel HAXM up and running fine on Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit (Core i3-2100 3.1 GHZ, 4 GB RAM).

About starting an Android emulator Intel x86 for API 21 with Use Host GPU enabled,

I had started it in just a first try using **JDK 64-bit**.

I can not start it even though waiting for a whole day using **JDK 32 bit**.

I hope this helps.